# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.4

I have a problem that I can not solve in any way with Laravel's migrations.

This is my users migration, data name is: 2014_12_10_000000_create_users_table.php

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->unsignedInteger('user_parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('company_id')->nullable();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

This is company table migration, filename is 2018_06_01_080858_create_company_table.php

```
Schema::create('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
             ....
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is instead a migration to set foreign keys, filename is: 2018_11_13_111338_alter_foreign_keys.php

```
Schema::table('users', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('user_parent_id')->references('id')->on('users');
          $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
      });
```

When I try to run php artisan:migrate I always have this error:

```
    In Connection.php line 647:                                                                               
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_company_id_foreign` foreign key (`company_id`) references `company` (`id`))                 

In PDOStatement.php line 144:                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint      
In PDOStatement.php line 142:                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

In last, migration, named 2018_11_13_111338_alter_foreign_keys.php I added all the other foreign keys in sequence, for all the other tables in my database.

Every suggestion is welcome, thank you.

This is code if alterForeignTable class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterForeignTable2 extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {


      Schema::table('users', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('user_parent_id')->references('id')->on('users');
          $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
      });


      Schema::table('otherstable', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add foreign keys to a table that has records in it already?

Comment: instead of `azienda` there should be `company`

Comment: @AmirhosseinDZ I have corrected the question, but this is not the problem.

Comment: @SasaBlagojevic I start from empty database, no records inside.

Comment: Please post the whole `2018_11_13_111338_alter_foreign_keys` migration.

Comment: @RobertoRemondini I've created a Laravel 5.4 project and your migrations work fine in my local env. Some common pitfalls that are easy to overlook are
1. The order of migrations execution.
2. Primary key and foreign key columns both need to be the same type and either UNSIGNED or SIGNED.

So be sure to double check this, and if possible try deleting the whole database and creating a new, before running migrations

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I added the migration's code in the question.

Comment: @SasaBlagojevic It is what I've done. Before I migrate all tables, without any foreign keys, after that, with a new migration, I try to add the foreign key for each table that I have created before. The type is unsignedInteger for foreign key and increments in the main table. I have also delete the whole database and creating a new, but the problem remains.

Comment: Does the foreign key on `user_parent_id` get created successfully?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, migrations fails but only the first foreign key was created successfully.

Comment: This is a very odd issue. I would suggest that you create a fresh Laravel installation with only these three migrations and try it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I tried with a new installation and only three migrations, the error is the same.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have two models and adding two foreign id. It is a many to many working. You just need add pivot table with company_id and user_id this article

https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't undestand your reply. Why Can't I ahve two foreign keys?

Comment: you can add foreign keys. Your relation that you say working with inverse and you need to working with many to many relation. It means that many company has many user and back!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to make your user_id field an index:

```
$table->index('user_id');
```

After that you can create a foreign key with an action on cascade:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

If you want to do that with a new migration, you have to remove the index and foreign key firstly and do everything from scratch.

On down() function you have to do this and then on up() do what I've wrote above:

```
$table->dropForeign('user_parent_id');
$table->dropIndex('lists_user_id_index');
$table->dropColumn('user_id');
```

> try this,hope it will work .